# Common page to "explore" different entities of data (users, vehicles, venues) on a website?

Tags: website-design

I have a website where registered users can add their vehicles (cars, motorcycles, trucks), track their expenses and connect them to different venues (filling stations, repair shops). So I want an area of the website called "explore" most likely, where everyone could go and browse (list) users, vehicles and venues to see some statistics.

All of them have different kinds of filters (for users it could be username match, or for vehicles it could be make/model/engine/tramission/etc), sorting options (like for users it will be reputation, registration date).

The main issue I have is I don't know how to present a good landing page to this explore section where users can get the idea that they can browse the different entities easily. Right now I'm thinking of something like big tabs, with pre-selected one of the entities that is most likely to be browsed...

If you could give an example of interface that solves similar problem, that would be amazing. Any suggestions in general are welcome.

Comment: Are you looking for an example of a car  or vehicle filtering dashboard?

Comment: No. I'm looking for a way to present a section, that will be intuitive for the users to browse through either "vehicles", "users" or "venues". So an entry point where they can browse one of the 3 entities. Every entity will have own page with own filters and such.

Answer (score 3):

Are you only concerned with only these three categories? Or are these just examples of the kinds of categories you want displayed?

If there are only going to be three categories on this "Explore" page, you could have a small subsection on the explore page dedicated to each. These subsections could highlight a handful of entries in each category, and give the user the option to dive deeper into a specific category of their choosing.

I really like [dribbble.com](http://dribbble.com/highlights)'s explore feature, and I think it might be something similar to what you're looking for. (Hover over the explore button at the top to see a few more example implementations)

The only problem would be if you wanted to start including more categories on the page. I think three is an optimal amount, but any more might start to feel cluttered.

Comment: Only those three categories actually. Users, vehicles, venues. Thanks for the dribbble's example! It really gives me ideas...

Answer (score 0):

I had similar situation. A website that users can get in and sell their cars or buy other cars. I have pages for adding car, purchasing car and technical service. So I put links to this sections in the main page(Think of a metro like style and you can easily put some statistics too).

For more user convenience you can put some simple filters inside a drop down section that will be appear when a users click on one of the above link. And when user click on submit button then show the items list.